# Modelling REST endpoints with data that not all users have access to

Tags: api, rest, modeling

I am trying to figure out the best way around a small problem i have with a design for a Hypermedia API i am currently building.

I have a notion of a site, very simple doesn't have much going on and it is accesible via:

- /sites
- /sites/{id}

Sites have a bunch of properties and none is all too sensitive.  However, a site has the notion of a budget, its nothing too exotic, in fact for the offset it will be a simple object that holds a decimal field and a pointer to a currency, but this should not be visible to every person requesting the resource as it is deemed as sensitive information that project managers should have.

Some options:

1. Just sent it - problem here is i don't know what the clients consuming the API will do with it and this is just a terrible option all round
2. Send down an empty object i.e. `Budget:{}`
3. Make `Budget` a sub-resource of `Site` and only give users with the appropriate access level access to it

As this is a hypermedia API i am leaning towards option 3, as i could(or not) as the case may be provide the link and also protect that endpoint separately, but at the same time this feels a little wrong, not sure why.

Item 3 could look like this:

- /sites/{id}/budget

Anyone out there with some helpful advice on something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Treat it as a sub-resource**

Your REST API should be decoupled from the internal domain model. Therefore you can provide a limited picture of your internal domain state through the REST API. This is one of the main features of REST.

To accomplish this, you may want to look into the [Hypertext Application Language (HAL)](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) representation.

Comment: I am already using HAL.  Issue comes with using WebAPI and typed objects with the formatter i am currently using.  I will look into altering it to see if i can ommit items.

Comment: In Java I've had a lot of success with [HalBuilder](https://github.com/HalBuilder). This might give you insight into how to construct/adjust your own.